# Audio is not being played when I convert the html5 game to Android using PhoneGap Cloud Build service

Tags: android, html, cordova, audio, construct

I had purchased an HTML5 game named BattleBattle from envato market. It is working fine in my pc when I publish it using IIS. I tried to convert this game to android apk file using PhoneGap Cloud Build service. The apk file is being generated and I am able to install and play the game in my mobile but the only problem is that there is no sound playing whereas sound plays in the browser. What could be the reason? The game is developed using Construct. I searched for solutions online but nothing helped. I even tried including audio plugins for phonegap but that too didn't help. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: can you show any codes what you have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the core media plugin. https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1168 and play the audio using it.

You will have to dig into the code and change the way the audio is initiated. Also remember that you will be only allowed to play one file at a time.